# javax.inject.Inject does not work

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, openjpa

In our project we did some Maven pom.xml cleanup and dependency injection stopped working. For example, this used to work but works no longer:

```
@Inject
private ItemService itemService;

public void whatever() {
    itemService.whatever();
}
```

The `itemService` is null when we run `whatever()`, no error/warning message present in log. There's only one bean implementing the interface:

```
public interface ItemService { ... }

@ContainerManaged
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
public class ItemServiceBean implements ItemService { ... }
```

We tried putting all the dependencies back in the project where this error occurs, but that didn't help. I don't know where to start looking. Any of these would be helpful:

- Where is the @Inject used? At runtime, by Spring? Is there some source code that would help? Perhaps the jar for that code is what we're missing?
- Is there some way to get some hint printed in the log? Even better would of course be some error at compile time, but that is probably pushing my luck...
- Best would of course be if you knew what dependency we're missing. :)  We're running Spring, OpenJPA and some more, but don't know what is relevant to list. If you know what to ask, I'll try my best to find the answer.

Comment: How is the object with ItemService field instantiated?

Comment: @BorisTreukhov: sounds like you're asking about [dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Include the following dependency in your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
  <version>1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Ah thanks, we had used `<provided>`, when removed it started working again.