# Error when trying to make a REST Call in Quarkus

Tags: java, rest, cdi, quarkus-rest-client

I'm trying to execute a request at another service that I own.
The guides I'm using to create the app are:

[QUARKUS - Using the REST Client](https://quarkus.io/guides/rest-client)

[QUARKUS - CDI Reference](https://quarkus.io/guides/cdi-reference)

[QUARKUS - Workshop](https://quarkus.io/quarkus-workshops/super-heroes/#fault-tolerance-rest-client)

I'm getting an error like:

```java
org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error injecting com.easy.ecomm.core.product.ProductClient com.easy.ecomm.core.cart.CartService.productClient

org.eclipse.microprofile.rest.client.RestClientDefinitionException: Parameters and variables don't match on interface com.easy.ecomm.core.product.ProductClient::findProductById
```

Here's the class ProductClient

```java
import org.eclipse.microprofile.rest.client.inject.RegisterRestClient;

@Path("products")
@RegisterRestClient(configKey = "products-api")
public interface ProductClient {

    @GET
    @Path("{id}")
    Product findProductById(String id);

}
```

Here's the Service Layer:

```java
import org.eclipse.microprofile.rest.client.inject.RestClient;

import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.inject.Inject;

@ApplicationScoped
public class CartService {

    @Inject
    @RestClient
    ProductClient productClient;

    public void addItem(String cartId, String productId, Integer amount){
        // Code to find the cart on a queue.
        Product product = findProduct(productId);
        cart.getItems().add(new CartItem(amount, product));
    }

    private Product findProduct(String productId) {
        return productClient.findProductById(productId);
    }
}
```

and the `application.properties`:

```java
products-api/mp-rest/url=http://localhost:8060
products-api/mp-rest/scope=javax.inject.Singleton
```

The dependencies are the same as we have on the guides `quarkus-rest-client` and `quarkus-rest-client-jackson`

Things that I've already tried:

Remove the ConfigKey from the `@RegisterRestClient` and use the full path on the `application.properties`, add the Jandex Plugin on my POM.xml as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55513502/how-to-create-a-jandex-index-in-quarkus-for-classes-in-a-external-module).

But still no success. Each change gives me the same error message.

Comment: Have you tried adding this pom dependency for a related error ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13629076/javax-inject-inject-does-not-work

Comment: Are you missing the `@PathParam` annotation on the argument of `findProductById`? I.e. try `findProductById(@PathParam String id)`

Comment: Add a @PathParam in your method

Comment: Yeah, @NikosParaskevopoulos you're right, I was missing the param.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You forgot to annotate your path variable with `@PathParam`, that's why it can't instantiate the client:

```
import org.eclipse.microprofile.rest.client.inject.RegisterRestClient;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;

@Path("products")
@RegisterRestClient(configKey = "products-api")
public interface ProductClient {

    @GET
    @Path("{id}")
    Product findProductById(@PathParam("id") String id);

}
```